# Dart interaction / access to database

Tags: html, dart

How can Dart (running server side) access a database ?

Can I execute SQL-Statements directly or can I use some kind of ORM?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently there is no Database API for Dart that rivals ODBC/JDBC, also to my knowledge there is no ORM. There will definitely be such a thing in the future, also the Dart SDK will eventually allow you to bind native code against it making it easier to provide database access by linking against existing database libraries.

I am myself currently using [Riak](http://wiki.basho.com/) on Dart via its REST interface, which works well for small applications but for something more serious we will have to await better SDK support.

**Note:** client side databases such as IndexDB and WebSQL are in the process of being [added](https://github.com/sethladd/lawndart/blob/master/lib/indexeddb-adapter.dart) to [dart:html](http://api.dartlang.org/html.html) right now.

**Update:** There is now a [MongoDB](https://github.com/vadimtsushko/mongo_dart/) driver and we are working on a driver for Amazon's DynamoDB

**Update 2:** Drivers are now available for [mysql](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqljocky) and [postgresql](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/postgresql).

Comment: What do you mean with "that rivals ODBC/JDBC"? Is there right now no way to make dart native a simple Query to a given DB: select * from persons;

Comment: @Gero yes that's what I mean. I currently know of no database drivers that are ported to Dart. But this will certainly arrive over the next couple of months.

Comment: @SethLadd I am just using the RIAK HTTP API http://wiki.basho.com/HTTP-API.html together with dart:io HTTPClient http://api.dartlang.org/io/HttpClient.html - nothing fancy

Answer (score 5):

There is a [mongoDb](https://bitbucket.org/vadimtsushko/mongo-dart) driver that Vadim Tsushko has released.  It was mentioned on the : [dartlang news](http://news.dartlang.org/2012/03/14-cool-projects-from-dart-community.html) recently.

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/maDdZNiu) for example usage.

**Update**: I've also blogged about it's usage on the [dartwatch blog](http://dartwatch.com/index.php/2012/03/building-a-client-server-dart-app-part-1-server-side/)

Comment: Pastebin link is not longer valid.

Comment: the "dartwatch blog" link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

This hits on a larger question of migrating from current architectures such as CakePHP and RoR to Dart.  Dart is very new and does not provide much functionality on the server side, not having db drivers is the least of your problems - Dart is lacking a tried and battle proven MVC framework which means that it is almost ludicrous to imagine migrating from CakePHP for the sake of argument to Dart.

In a situation where you want to try and start converging to the Dart goals - it would make sense NOT to access the db directly from Dart but to use RESTful services in an existing MVC framework.

This provides a much cleaner and robust interface than coding to SQL in Dart and provides a good migration path.

Comment: ofc, but if python or php can access a db, so should dart be able too! I think in few months there will be a dart beta and i hope for some signs of an ORM Framework.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a Redis driver available: https://github.com/mythz/DartRedisClient

Answer (score 0):

There is also a Windows MS-SQL Server driver available at https://pub.dev/packages/dart_mssql