# can Dart be used for basic CRUD web application?

Tags: crud, dart

I just discovered this Language and I'd like to know if it's possible to make basic CRUD web app using a database.

Answer (score 3):

There are libraries for [mysql](https://github.com/jamesots/sqljocky) and [postgresql](https://github.com/xxgreg/postgresql), and the core library provides a [web server](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/HttpServer.html) with HTTP, HTTPS and WebSocket support.

There is a [templating](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/#svn/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/utils/template) library which isn't part of the official release. And, there is also a community  [mustache](https://github.com/valotas/mustache4dart) port (I don't think it builds at the moment, so you may need to fix it).

So it's definitely possible. But you'll be an early adopter. If you want to get stuff done quick, I'd choose something else, but if you're wanting to learn new skills, dive in.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  It's a pretty new language though so you aren't going to find the robust library support you will in other languages just yet.  It's rapidly growing however so I don't think it will be long.  You can either write your server in dart or write your server in another language and expose a basic HTTP interface for your Dart client to consume.

Here is an [example](http://blog.dartwatch.com/2012/03/building-client-server-dart-app-part-1.html) of writing a simple web application which creates and stores "blog" posts.  Both the client and server are written in Dart.  The database is MongoDB.

Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558282/dart-interaction-access-to-database) for more information.